# how to show json object key and value using handlebar template?

Tags: jquery, json, handlebars.js

I have started to learn handlebar.js . I am struggling to display json data .

My json look like this:

```
 var data={
          "record1":
          [
             {
               "first":
                      [
                       {
                         "name":"john",
                         "city":"newyork"  
                       },
                       {
                         "name":"britto",
                         "city":"bangalore"  
                       }
                      ]
             },
            {"second":
                 [
                  {
                    "name":"franklin",
                    "city":"newyork"  
                  },
                  {
                    "name":"leo",
                    "city":"bangalore"  
                  }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
```

here this json is coming from server response so I don't know any key and value. I have to show key and value dynamically by using handlebar ...I have tried with eachKey but I have not got solution for that . Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 34):

You can render the keys/values of a list in a Handlebars template like this:

```
{{#each object}}
  {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: i have tried with list but that is showing project key but value is object

Comment: You have to drill down the data-structure a bit, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gV7YZ/) for an example with your data.

Comment: I find the way to access key and found this question. But some of my json data is array. So ``@key`` will never work, use ``@index`` instead.
This is for who are searching for access key in array.
Thank you @tobi.

Comment: I don't see why `@value` isn't default, but `this` works. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

First thank you tobi this did lead to what I needed getting the key.

In case it was not clear for the OP "this" is referring to the current object of that iteration.

So in your case data the object has the array record1 with 2 objects that are arrays of objects: first and second.

Using each:

```
{{#each record1}}
    {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

would give you: 
first: (object, array)
second: (object, array)

You will be looping over the object (data). In this if you wanted to dig down you would need a counter to get anywhere further. I would recommend using a handlebars block helper to get there.

Here is the documentation: http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

Answer (score 2):

For objects:

```
{{#each myObject}}
    Key: {{@key}} Value = {{this}} //renders object like {key: value}
{{/each}}
```

Note that only properties passing the `hasOwnProperty` test will be enumerated.

---

For arrays:

```
{{#each myArray}}
    Index: {{@index}} Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
```